# MoveFile() for replacing an existing file does not work on Release but works fine on Debug (C++)

Tags: c++

I use MoveFile() to move a file ("file_") and overwrite another ("file") within the same directory in one step.

```
MoveFile(file_, file);
```

This works fine on Debug but on Release the function returns: 
 HRESULT 800700b7: 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.'

Why is that different behavior between Debug and Release and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Solution to overwrite a file is to use:

```
MoveFileEx(file_, file, MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

The documentation to MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING says:

> If a file named lpNewFileName exists, the function replaces its
>   contents with the contents of the lpExistingFileName file, provided
>   that security requirements regarding access control lists (ACLs) are
>   met.

It may be that MoveFile() does not provide that security requirements needed. 
Yet the Question for the different behavior between Debug and Release is not answered.